# Cannot access Oracle Enterprise Manager from outside the Azure VM

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a new VM based on the Oracle 11g template. I did all configuration steps and I can access my Oracle instance from inside the VM, including the Oracle Enterprise Manager.

I opened the ports in the firewall of the VM and I created the Endpoints in the Azure management portal, as described in tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn439775.aspx, in section "Enabling Oracle Database Enterprise Manager remote access", to access the Enterprise Manager remotely. This doesn't work. I also followed the steps in "Allow your database to be reached remotely" and I can't access the database.

[image: Endpoints]
[image: Firewall]

In summary, I can RDP to the vm using port 3389 but I can't access the other services in ports 1521 and 1158. I double checked these ports, they are valid and they are open in the firewall.

I also made sure there was a listener running in the VM for allowing connections to the database.

If I access https://my-vm-name-xxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net:1158/em from within the VM it works fine. From the outside I get no response.

Any ideas on what is going on or how to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Which IP address are the listener/OEM using?

Comment: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MY_AZURE_VM_NAME)(PORT=1521))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting here.

I was able to reproduce the issue. I found thatyou need to enable both 1158 and 1521 ports on VM and management portal. Along with that you should enable 5500 inside the VM and management portal. If you are accessing outside VM use this link https://my-vm-name-xxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net:5500/em

!ports on azure portal][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRO9q.jpg)

[image]

[image]
Hope this helps you.

Girish Prajwal

Answer (score -1):

You need to open ports in your OS Firewall and open VM endpoints either using Azure portal or powershell.

Navigate to Virtual Machines >> Select VM >> Endpoints tab >> Add.

**How to Set Up Endpoints to a Virtual Machine**

http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Comment: I did that. I mentioned it in the question. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: ah ok! didn't see your update. Can you access these services from other VMs inside azure?

Comment: No problem. Any other idea? :)

Comment: I can only think of 3 possible scenarios: Application is blocking the access, windows firewall or azure endpoints. I never used Oracle but for Sql Server and Mysql you have to manually add external ip addresses which will have permissions to access the services. Maybe Oracle works the same way?

Comment: I'm a dev, not an infra guy. What do you mean with add external ip's to the services?

Comment: Seems to me from the article you send you didn't follow the instructions properly for this part "Enabling Oracle Database Enterprise Manager remote access". Looks like Enterprise Manager uses port 5500 for public access. Try opening this port in windows firewall and azure endpoint. Also, it is http, not https. http://<<unique_domain_name>>:5500/em